# If $A=B-C$, does $B=A\cup C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can't seem to figure this one out!

If $A=B-C$, then $B=A\cup C$.

Can anyone help me out here?

I've tried to find a counterargument, but I can't place one.

EDIT:
So I came up with a counterexample:
$B=\{c, d, e\}$
$C=\{f, g, h\}$
$A= \{c, d, e\}$

So $A\cup C=\{c, d, e, f, g, h\}$ which doesn't equal $B$.

That works, right?

Comment: Drawing a Venn Diagram can sometimes help with questions like this.

Comment: $B=\{1\}, C=\{2\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=B-C$, then

$A \cup C=(B - C) \cup C=B \cup C=B\cup (B^{c} \cap C)$

So $B=A∪C$ if and only if $B^{c} \cap C= \varnothing$ or $C \subseteq B$

So any $C$ that $C \nsubseteq B$ will be counterexample. Your case is right.

Comment: Ok wow. I feel really stupid. Thank you so much!

Comment: It might be helpful for you when writing math to use the code for the math symbols.  You already know to put math between dollar signs.  When you are writing math between dollar signs signs, to get $ \cup$, just write $ \text{ \cup }$.  Similarly, to get:  $\cap$ write $\text{ \cap } $, $\subseteq$ write $\text{ \subseteq }$.

Comment: @Zhang If you want to write something like $\bigcup \limits_{x \in Y}$, you would write $\text{\bigcup \limits_{x \in Y}  }$.  If you want to write something under a limit, like $\lim \limits_{x \to a }$, you would write $\text{ \lim \limits_{x \to a }}$.  You can't use $\cup$ ($\text{ \cup } $) if you want to write something under the union.  You have to use $\bigcup$ ($\text{\bigcup}$).